# nullable error when implementing react-native-admob in android

Tags: nullable

I have added react-native-admob in my project but when i open my project in android studio and try to run my project, i face below error

`react-native-admob:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
Desktop/myapp/node_modules/react-native-admob/android/src/main/java/com/sbugert/rnadmob/RNAdMobInterstitialAdModule.java:5: error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;`